# Updating Microsoft aspnet mvc 5 failed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, umbraco

I'm trying to install Umbraco in a fresh .NET MVC project in VS Express for Web 2013.

If I choose .Net Framework 4.5 or 4.5.1, then try to install Umbraco via Nuget, I get the following error:

> Updating Microsoft.aspnet.mvc 5.2.3 to Microsoft.aspnet.mvc 4.0.20710.0 failed. Unable to find a version of UmbracoCms.Core that is conpatible with Microsoft.aspnet.mvc 4.0.20710.0.

I've tried changing the target framework to 4.5 then back to 4.5.1 and also tried unistalling `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` via package manager and reinstalling but no joy.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with the version of Umbraco you are trying to install.

May I point you towards the following blog post, which may be of help:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/64654-MVC-5-Umbraco-Nuget-Install

Alternatively, have you not tried to do a manual installation of Umbraco? I prefer this option (I get a lot more control :P).

See the following guide for manually installing Umbraco: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/installation/install-umbraco-manually

During a manual installation I would create a blank visual studio solution (MVC or WebForms) and import the Umbraco files into the solution.

The following blog gives a good example of this:
http://www.harshbaid.in/2014/04/30/umbraco-cms-asp-net-mvc-part-3-inside-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tried the process in the blog and it didn't help but didn't have time to try a manual install. Will try tonight and let you know.

Comment: Tried the manual install which installs Umbraco in Webmatrix but doesn't help me with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes. Installing this via Nuget resolves this issue and Umbraco should install without problems.